# XCode 7.3.1 very odd autocomplete error

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

[image: Issue with XCode 7.3.1 autocomplete]

Something odd has started happening with a new Swift project I've created

You can see that I have a class called ViewController which is of type UIViewController

I have a function called someFunction that takes an input String? and give a String of "ABCDEFG". Simple right?

Well when I try to assign a class variable the output of that function you can see that autocomplete thinks someFunction requires (self: ViewController) input and it should instead take a String? input

Does anyone know what is happening here? It's driving me crazy

Comment: You cannot instantiate a standard stored property to reference some instance method. You can, though, if (a) you declare the variable to be `lazy`; and (b) explicitly reference `self`, e.g. `lazy var someVariable: String = self.someFunction("foo")`. The autocomplete in this scenario is still flaky, though.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I derped pretty hard.

I was trying to utilize a member only function from within a scope where the class hadn't been instantiated.

Instantiate your classes first kids...